# Re-animating in slide when navigated to: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, fullpage.js

I have a one page website which makes use of full-screen slides(powered by [fullPage.js](http://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)).

I have this script running to animate some text when the page first loads (the first page is the one with animation)
Im fairly new to JS so I was wondering how I would make it perform the animation every-time the user navigates to the slide?

`JS`:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fn.fullpage({
            slidesColor: ['#161616', '#161616'],
            anchors: ['', 'Bye']});

        $(".test").each(function(i) {
            $(this).delay(i*600).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 700)
        });         
    });
</script>
```

It just animates three `spans`. 
I'd like it to animate them again when I navigate back to the slide. Also how do I get it to set the `opacity` = 0 when navigated to another slide?(so that it can be reanimated

`HTML`:

```
<div class="section active" id="section0">
<h1>?</h1>
<h2><span class="test">1.</span> <span class="test">2.</span> <span class="test">3.</span></h2>
<a  onclick="javascript:window.location='#CV';"><img class="downArrow" src="images/arrow.svg"/></a>
```

`CSS` for `.test`:

```
   .test{
       opacity: 0;
   }
```

Comment: Can you set up a www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I dont know how to add the other JS plugins into it?
I will check it out a bit later, 3am here need some sleep!

Comment: Ok sounds good man. You would put a link to the plugin in the `External Resources` section on the left in the jsfiddle dashboard.

Comment: The callbacks provided with the plugin `afterSlideLoad` and `afterSlideLeave` offer everything you need.

Comment: Ross can you give me an example of the code I would use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is how I did it. Notice I used `fadeOut()` to change the `opacity`, this was because changing the `css` `opacity` was unstable sometimes it wouldnt change all the elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.fn.fullpage({
            anchors: ['1', '2'],

            afterRender: function(){
            //For the initial animation, aferLoad does not work.
                $(".test").each(function(i){
                    $(this).delay(i*600).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 900);
                });
            },

            afterLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
            //When the first slide is navigated to perform animation.
                if(anchorLink == '1'){
                    $(".test").each(function(i){
                        $(this).delay(i*600).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 900);
                    });
                }
            },

            onLeave: function(index, direction){
            //When navigated away from first slide reset the opacity.
                if(index == '1' && direction == 'down'){
                    $(".test").fadeTo(400,0);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```